# how to validate connection strings of azure iot hub in spark streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

i'm new to azure iot hub . im trying to pull message from azure iot hub using spark streaming . im getting error when i execute the code and i could understand there is some problem in connection strings. is there any specific way to validate the connection string in spark and also please tell me the format which i specified is correct or not .

My sample code:

```
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs._

val eventHubName = "xyztest.azure-devices.net"
val eventHubNSConnStr = "Endpoint=sb://testname.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=primary;SharedAccessKey=abcedfgrdxyeurjrsdfyasdf="
val connStr = ConnectionStringBuilder(eventHubNSConnStr).setEventHubName(eventHubName).build 
val customEventhubParameters = EventHubsConf(connStr).setMaxEventsPerTrigger(5)
val incomingStream = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(customEventhubParameters.toMap).load()
incomingStream.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("truncate", false).start().awaitTermination()
```

Errro:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.IllegalEntityException: The messaging entity 'sb://testname.servicebus.windows.net/xyztest' could not be found.
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
        at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.partitionCount(EventHubsClient.scala:169)
```

Comment: Hi Krishnaraj, if the answer solved your issue you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If not, feel free let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> val eventHubName = "xyztest.azure-devices.net"

It seems you set wrong event hub name. "xyztest.azure-devices.net" should be your Azure IoT Hub hostname.

To find the event hub name you can go your iot hub-> endpoints-> events and copy the value of Event Hub-compatible name like this:

[image]

In the end, the [event hub connect string](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/spark-streaming-eventhubs-integration.md#connection-string) will have the following format:

> Endpoint=sb://SAMPLE;SharedAccessKeyName=KEY_NAME;SharedAccessKey=KEY;EntityPath=EVENTHUB_NAME

Comment: @KrishnarajGunasekar Glad to help. If you can accept this answer we can close this issue and it also will be helpful for others need. About how to accept the answer you can reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: hey Ritan, sorry for the delay . where can i give Acceptance? . i was searching for "Acceptance" button .

Comment: @KrishnarajGunasekar Acceptance is indicated by a colored checkmark next to the answer that has been accepted by the original author of the question.

Comment: done . Thanks for your support . can i add one more question here related to kafka ?

Comment: @KrishnarajGunasekar You can ask a new question adding the related tags. We can see it and help you.